# Link docker containers (Drupal and MariaDB)

Tags: docker, drupal, mariadb

To start I built a docker container from the MariaDB docker image.
After that I loaded a database dumpfile in the running container.

```
[MariaDB status][1]
```

Everything goes fine.
When I want to run/link the Drupal image:

```
docker run --name drupaldocker --link mariadbdocker:mariadb -p 8089:80 -d drupal
```

I can reach the drupal installation page, but when I want to load the database I always have the same errors:

-host, pass or dbname is wrong.

But I'm pretty sure my credentials are right.
It seems that my drupal container can't find the mariadb image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker links is a deprecated feature and should be avoided: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

I assume you have a container named mariadbdocker running. 
If you gain bash access inside drupaldocker container, you should be able to ping mariadb alias like this:

`docker run --name drupaldocker --link mariadbdocker:mariadb -p 8089:80 -it drupal /bin/bash`

If ping succeeds then you probably still have credentials issue.